# xsltproc suppress entity resolving

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to do a simple transform om a docbook xml file.
however we he entities defined in a DTD which are referenced in this xml file.

because the transform is separate from the rest of our docbook chain we need to keep the entity references as references in the result.

i have tried with --novalid an --nodtdattr but it still resolves the entities (or drops them).

is there a way to force xlstproc / xs;t to keep the entity-references or reinsert them?
(allready using disable-output-escaping="yes" on text nodes in my transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass entity references through a transform. You have to preprocess the source, e.g. transform the entity references to elements, and convert them back to entities after the transform.

Comment: this is basicaly my problem, it seems odd to me that a xml transformation language is incapable of the indentity transform :s